# How to implement a function that prints the sum of distance between each number in a matrice using loops?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, while-loop, primes

"print_sieves(105)" prints all the prime numbers up to 105. Once this is done the numbers will be printed in a matrice with 6 numbers horizontally before breaking to the next column.

I want to calculate the sum of the distance between consecutive primes ([2,3]+[3,5]+[5,7]) etc. all the way up to 105 and print the sum.
For clarification the distance between 2 and 3 is 1, the distance between 3 and 5 is 2 etc.

I have added a function under "void print_sieves" to print out how many occurences of a length of 4 between the primes. If the occurences found is, for instance 8, I multiply 4*8 and I get the distance I'm looking for.

I can continue doing this by copying and pasting this code and looking for a distance from 1-10 and solve my dilemma finally by adding all the values I have found. However the code will be very long.

Is there a more efficent way of doing this using maybe loops or if/else statements?

```
/*
 Program name - sieves.c 
 This program implements the sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm for finding prime numbers.
 The user inputs a number, and the program will print out all prime numbers up to that input and the
 distance between their numbers combined.
*/


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h> // To measure execution time

#define COLUMNS 6

int column_count = 0;

void print_number(int number){
  printf("%10d ", number);
  column_count++;
  if(column_count%COLUMNS == 0){ // Every 6th entry will yield 0
    printf("\n");
  }
}

// The function that implements the sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm.
// This function has one parameter that states the max prime number values.

void print_sieves(int input)
   {
    // Initialize the array we will work with
    int array_size = input - 1;
    // Local array declaration
    char numbers[array_size];

    // Populate the array with 1's (True values)
    for(int entry = 0; entry < array_size; entry++){
      numbers[entry] = 1;
    }

    // Check the factors up to the square of the input, since that is
    // the last number that can be squared to produce the input.
    for(int i = 2; i <= (int) sqrt(input); i++){
      if(numbers[i] == 1){ // This is to check if we already covered a number
        for(int j = i*i; j <= input; j+=i){ // For every multiple of that number
          numbers[j] = 0; // Mark it as non-prime
        }
      }
    }

    // Printing out the true values from the array, starting from the "2"
    for(int i = 2; i <= array_size; i++){
      if(numbers[i] == 1){
        print_number(i);
      }
    }

    // Print out how many occurences of a length of 4 between the primes.
    int steps = 0;
    int x = 0; // prime x < y
    for(int y = 2; y <= array_size; y++){
      if(numbers[y] == 1){ // When we get to next prime
        if(y - x == 4){
          steps++;
        }
        x = y; // assign x to y so we calculate from there next time
      }
    }

    printf("\n\nNumber of occurences with 4 steps between primes: %d\n", steps);
}

// 'argc' contains the number of program arguments, and
// 'argv' is an array of char pointers, where each
// char pointer points to a null-terminated string.
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  // Uncomment this segment below for using input in terminal
  /* if(argc == 2)
    print_primes(atoi(argv[1]));
  else
    printf("Please state an interger number.\n"); 
  */

  print_sieves(105);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your task: "I want to calculate the sum of the distance between each prime number i.e. 3-2=1, 5-3=2 etc. all the way up to ". Let's stop at 10. You have these primes: 2, 3, 5, 7. Do you want to compute a) the sum of the distances between **consecutive** primes ([2,3]+[3,5]+[5,7]), or b) the sum of the distances between **all** primes ([2,3]+[2,5]+[2,7]+[3,5]+[3,7]+[5,7])?

Comment: I am sorry, I meant consecutive primes and not all primes. I will add that to my description straight away

Comment: distance(2,3) + distance(3,5) + distance(5,7) = (3 - 2) + (5 - 3) + (7 - 5) = 7 - 2 = 5. Why all this trouble? :-)

Comment: @Dominique ‍♂️ I didn't see it... Maybe the problem may be made more interesting by changing it to "the sum of the squared distances between consecutive primes"?

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide an answer to the question (from Dominique's comment):

```
    for (int i = array_size - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        if (numbers[i] == 1){ // When we get to largest prime
            printf("\n\nSum of distances between consecutive primes: %d\n", i - 2);
            break;
        }
    }
```

If you want to get the (unrequested) sum of squared distances between consecutive primes:

```
    int sum = 0;
    int x = 2;
    for(int y = 3; y < array_size; y++) {
        if(numbers[y] == 1){ // When we get to next prime
            int dist = y - x;
            sum += dist*dist;
            x = y; // assign x to y so we calculate from there next time
        }
    }
    printf("\n\nSum of the squared distances between consecutive primes: %d\n", sum);
```

Notice the `y < array_size`. You were using `y <= array_size`, which is a classic mistake.